# What's the fastest way to interpret a nested javascript object attribute accessor string?

Tags: javascript, nested, backbone.js, eval, accessor

Say I have a nested object structure like:

```
var o = { a: { b: { c: 1 } } };
```

and I have a an accessor `String` like `"a.b.c"`.

What's the fastest function to return the specified nested value (to any depth [1..n])?

I.e. in this case,  `getNested(o, 'a.b.c') === 1` and `getNested(o, 'a') === {b:{c:1}}`.

What's the best implementation of `getNested`?

Comment: I have a feeling this is implementation-dependent, a race between the much-maligned and evil `eval` and splitting up `a.b.c` into `t` and producing `o[t[0]][t[1]][t[2]]`.  I suspect `eval` is slow, though....

Comment: those are all useful answers, pretty well spans the solution space. anyone want to post a benchmark to see which is fastest across relevant browser engines?

Comment: @rayt the most straightforward is the fastest (at least on Chrome.) ~harto slower by ~10%  ~4esn0k slower by about ~30%  ~kennebec slower by an order of magnitude

Comment: I added a js-perf for this and it seems the for loop is fastest, though could do with a check: http://jsperf.com/get-nested2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to give an answer without profiling the code myself, but given that `eval` is probably slow, and `forEach` is slower than just running through a for-loop, I would start with:

```
// precondtion: path is a nonempty string
function getNested(obj, path) {
    var fields = path.split(".");
    var result = obj;
    for (var i = 0, n = fields.length; i < n; i++) {
        result = result[fields[i]];
    }
    return result;
}
```

But I would test this against other approaches.

I don't think that trying to optimize away the array construction on `split` would be worthwhile, but this is only one thing to try if you are interested in **the** fastest way.

**ADDENDUM**

Here is a transcript so you can see it in action:

```
$ node
> function getNested(obj, path) {
...     var fields = path.split(".");
...     var result = obj;
...     for (var i = 0, n = fields.length; i < n; i++) {
...         result = result[fields[i]];
...     }
...     return result;
... }
> var o = { a: { b: { c: 1 } } };
> getNested(o, "a")
{ b: { c: 1 } }
> getNested(o, "a.b.c")
1
```

** ADDENDUM 2 **

So embarassing -- I forgot the `var` in front of `result` before.  That might speed it up a bit!

Other things to try:

- Forget about the "optimization" with `n` and just do the for-loop test with `i < test.length` (might be optimized away anyway)
- Replace split with `substring`s and `indexOf`s
- Do the split with a regex `/\./` instead of a raw string `"."`

Comment: what would you try to make it faster yet?

Comment: I added some suggestions to the answer.  Also see in the second addendum where I fixed up the code a little.  I had forgotten to say `var` in front of `result` so all uses of `result` were accessing the global namespace which is likely slower than having it local.

Answer (score 3):

one more variant:

```
function getNested(obj, path) {
  path.replace(/[^\.]+/g, function (p) {
    obj = obj[p];
  });
  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
function getNested(o, path) {
    var parts = path.split('.');
    var member = o;
    while (member && parts.length) {
        member = member[parts.shift()];
    }
    return member;
}
```

It's probably not the fastest possible solution, but might be a useful starting point.

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
   var prop=eval(string);
}
catch(er){
   prop=undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach

```
var o = { a: { b: { c: 1 } } };
var getNested = function(p) {
    var t;
    p.split('.').forEach(function(e) {
        t = o[e] || t[e]
    });
    return t
}
```

you can try:

```
getNested('a.b.c')
```